# Seeking a survey of community-accepted specific applications of XML

Tags: xml, xsd

[Wikipedia list -- 'business and industry'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Industry-specific_XML-based_standards)
[List by Doug Barry, a consultant](http://www.service-architecture.com/xml/articles/common_xml_vocabularies.html)
These are about all I can find for lists of generally-accepted applications for XML.  This mystifies me.  I feel sure there are lots more in use or under development, and I'd think everyone would be eager to see them promoted and cross-pollinated.

What got me going on this was a review of the [SGF file format](http://www.red-bean.com/sgf/) for recording board games.  As I expected must be the case, there's an [XML replacement](http://senseis.xmp.net/?XGF) underway.  I know some mind mapping programs use XML for storing files.  Flow-charting (and similar diagramming) is another area I'd expect to be handled.

Do you know of a clearing-house resource with more complete information about XML in  its various specific usages?

Comment: Finding a comprehensive list of XML applications seems only slightly more plausible to me than finding a comprehensive list of file formats that use 7-bit ASCII. ".xml" is the ".dat" of the 21st century.

Comment: You can use XML for whatever you want ... really!

Comment: Here's another list, from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_technologies.asp

Comment: @Laurence:  I agree!  A "comprehensive list" would be too much to ask.  What surprises me is that the lists I've cited are the fullest ones I've seen, and they strike me as scant.

Comment: @ Pop:  Yes, I know that.  Thanks.  
@ MatrixFrog:  That's a bit of a meta-view; but your site includes http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_real_life.asp, which is closer (but offers only 2 examples).  Thanks.

Comment: Heh heh .... I said 'cross-pollinated,' but I guess I didn't mean that either literally or figuratively!  I'm sure I meant something, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:  [xml.coverpages.org](http://xml.coverpages.org/techReports.html).
The key was searching on "Survey XML Schema" and chasing a link or two.

Comment: Of course now I'm finding the holes ... where's KML?  http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html

Answer (score 1):

XML is considered more or less a universal way to store information of all kinds, especially if you are sharing data between two different computer systems over the internet.  So there is no generally-accepted cross-section of programs for which XML is (not) appropriate.

XML is a somewhat "heavy" way of representing information, which is why alternate representations of data exist.  In particular, JSON is becoming popular as an alternate data interchange format for certain uses such as Ajax calls.

Comment: I'm not looking for a list of "programs for which XML is (not) appropriate."  XML is generic text-based data, so it's app-agnostic.  It can be "shaped" or configured.  This essential quality is not a requirement for putting it to work, but has apparently been very helpful for some disciplines or business realms, etc.  I hope to learn about those configurations.

Comment: -1 as this answer was not helpful.  I think you'll find the answer I just posted is a straight-up helpful answer.  I apologize if I failed in communicating clearly.

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad you found what you needed.